# Could not dispatch a message to the daemon

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

when i execute "gradle assembleRelease",sometimes i get a error :

```
03:23:01.987 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
03:23:01.987 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
03:23:01.988 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
03:23:01.988 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Could not dispatch a message to the daemon.
03:23:01.988 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
03:23:01.988 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
03:23:01.989 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonConnectionException: Could not dispatch a message to the daemon.
03:23:01.989 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection.dispatch(DaemonClientConnection.java:72)
03:23:01.990 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(DaemonClient.java:167)
03:23:01.990 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.SingleUseDaemonClient.execute(SingleUseDaemonClient.java:55)
03:23:01.990 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.SingleUseDaemonClient.execute(SingleUseDaemonClient.java:37)
03:23:01.990 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
03:23:01.990 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
03:23:01.991 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
03:23:01.991 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
03:23:01.991 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
03:23:01.991 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
03:23:01.992 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
03:23:01.992 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
03:23:01.992 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
03:23:01.992 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
03:23:01.992 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
03:23:01.993 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
03:23:01.993 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
03:23:01.993 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
03:23:01.993 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
03:23:01.993 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
03:23:01.994 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
03:23:01.994 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
03:23:01.994 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
03:23:01.994 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.MessageIOException: Could not write message org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Finished@266bad10 to '/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:53366'.
03:23:01.994 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.dispatch(SocketConnection.java:111)
03:23:01.995 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection.dispatch(DaemonClientConnection.java:63)
03:23:01.995 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 22 more
03:23:01.995 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
03:23:01.995 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
03:23:01.996 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
03:23:01.996 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
03:23:01.996 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
03:23:01.996 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:487)
03:23:01.996 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection$SocketOutputStream.flush(SocketConnection.java:236)
03:23:01.997 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.dispatch(SocketConnection.java:109)
03:23:01.997 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 23 more
```

the gradle version is 2.7.

I can't find any information about this error,Want to know about it can give me some inspiration,thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try restarting the daemon.  Perhaps it was killed for some reason

`gradle --stop && gradle clean build`

Comment: > Task :sqflite:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Answer (score 2):

for me it was about GRADLE_HOME environmental variable. I hadn't set GRADLE_HOME.

these steps might help:

1. point to advanced system settings -> environmental variables
2. make an environmental variable named "GRADLE_HOME"
3. give the address of your gradle file (you can find it on Users -> YOUR_USER_NAME -> .gradle -> GRADLE_VERSION (like: 4.4) or if you didn't find it here, you can download one from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ and extract it in the path mentioned and give it's directory address for the GRADLE_HOME variable.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my issue by installing the version 8 of the OpenJDK Hotspot JVM. Previously I was using version 11 of the OpenJDK OpenJ9 JVM. Not sure if it's because I went from V11 to V8 or from OpenJ9 to Hotspot.

Comment: For me it was a version issue as well.  I couldn't get 6.7 or 6.6.1 to work with latest OpenJDK15, once I moved back to 14, it worked again.

Comment: @gagarwa I had trouble too, but 6.6.1 was actually the latest version that at least could output version information. Newer Gradle versions couldn't even do that... https://discuss.gradle.org/t/installation-trouble/38702

Answer (score 1):

I drop the folder of gradle in my home

```
rm -Rf ~/.gradle
```

it's works for me.

Comment: drawback: you also remove your private gradle configuration

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was simply a lack of heap memory.
I found out the reason by trying to start the daemon manually with

```
gradle --daemon
```

That produced the following error message:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

Answer (score 0):

`cd android && gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android`
Hit this command from Project root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just delete the daemon files, just look for the corresponding version in *~/.gradle/daemon* and delete them

Answer (score 0):

For me (Cordova/Ionic Project), stopping cleaning didn't work because Gradle Daemon was not being properly used in the build. I have IBM JRE also installed in my machine as in my Environment PATH variable.

So I opened android folder in Android Studio and build was success, but with this warning.
that Gradle Daemon is using 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre' with couple of more warnings for not using JRE set in PATH.

so for my cordova project I had to this

```
cd platforms/android/ && gradlew.bat clean build -Dorg.gradle.java.home="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre"
```

And build success!

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me.
just add this line on your gradlew.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```